# Find singularities of function $f(z)=|z|^2 + 1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

**Question**: find all singular points of function $f(z)=|z|^2+\frac{1}{z}$

**My attempt**:

Since we can be written as, $f(z)=z\bar{z}+\frac{1}{z}$

$$→\frac{∂f}{∂\bar{z}}=z$$

$$=0 \text{  if and only if  }z=0$$

So it follows that, $f$ is not differentiable when $z≠0$(**is am I correct?**)

**What about $z=0$ ? Is it singular point ?** Further, what types of singularities $f$ have?

Please help me.... stuck on it :-(

Answer (score 1):

If a function is holomorphic, then 
$\frac{∂f}{∂\overline{z}}=0$ so taking the contrapositive gives you that f is not differentiable (thus not analytic) when $z\neq 0$. If you look closely at your function, $1/z$ blows up when $z=0$, hence $z=0$ is also a singularity and your function has singularites $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Sir, the points where function is fails to be analytic is called "singular point". So here we had seen when $z≠0$ function is not analytic. So points for which $z≠0$ must be singular points? where I am goes wrong? Please sir..explain me....

Comment: just edited it ! Don't hesitate if you have other questions wrt to what i wrote above

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your help, , what you wrote fine sir. But, the book key says z=0 is singular point(they didn't mentioned about other singular points) Is book key is wrong? Though book is very nicely written and reputed book.

Comment: @Malik according to standard terminology poles are isolated singularities. To say f has a pole at a point c we have to make sure that it is analytic in some neighborhood of c after c is deleted from the neighborhood. According to this$z=0$ is not a pole.

Comment: I totally agree, forgot about this detail ahah

Comment: Sir, is now, what are set of singular points is it $\mathbb{C}$? But book key say $z=0$ is only singularity :-(

Comment: According to what you can find on the internet, points where a function is not analytic are also singular points. Check again in the book how they define singular points, terminology often differs depending on the author.